# Is it possible to send and receive MMS using Azure Communication Services?

Tags: azure, mms, azure-communication-services

I know SMS is possible using Azure Comm. Service, but what about sending/receiving MMS images and videos?

Is this possible?

If not, are there other options besides ACS to use MMS in Azure?

Comment: please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview).

Comment: The term "MMS" does not appear in this doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (2022/09) Azure Communication Services doesn't yet support MMS, but it is in the works.

Comment: Is there a roadmap document for Azure Comm Services you can point me to?

Comment: Check out [this one](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/blob/master/roadmap.md). It doesn't go too far out yet, but you can keep an eye out for any updates there.